# Dynamic redirecting all subdomains with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've got the following code that will redirect "www.domain.com" to "domain.com". This is fine but I want it to redirect all subdomains, ie. "test.domain.com" to "domain.com" as well. It has to be dynamic, meaning that the domain name can't be hardcoded.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've tried various stuff but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It supports `anything.example.com` and redirects to `example.com` and `example.com` can be served on the same site using the redirect.